# How to store images into database using php in android?

Tags: java, android, android-image

Hi i want to store images into database.I created table with fields like imgID tinyint, image blob. But i have a little bit confusion on it.Can any body tel me how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert Images/Bitmaps into byte array and then add it to the database as blob. 
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrive-it) post

Answer (score 1):

I've always stored the image file name/location. And just linked to it ... without storing the image as a blob.

Its simpler: database won't get massive and functionally it does almost the same thing.