# How to save images in Android?

Tags: android, camera, save

I'm very new to Android programming and I was wondering how can I make an app take a picture and save the image to the internal storage of a device, not to the SD card, because not everyone will have an SD card.

Answer (score 1):

You can try saving it as an sqlite blob.  This [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrive-it) thread for how to do the storage.  Saying "not everyone will have external storage" is a  bad excuse: you should handle both cases.  If instead you want to implement it as a file (a perfectly good way to do it), you can look up an external storage directory using the Environment.getExternalStorageDir() call to determine a suitable directory in which to store your files.  Read the API documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and heed the following note:

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try to save images in sqlite blob fields. It's just a java way: and let the whole world wait :)

It's a good practice to store all your files, cache etc into `/Android/data/<package_name>/files/` directory on external storage. *External storage* is not the only SD cards and you can get external storage path and state by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getExternalStorageState() calls ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)). If you are using API 8 or greater, you can use Context.getExternalFilesDir().

If you would like to get user's hate-rays, you can try to store files and folders in the root of external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
 Bitmap largeBitmap ;  // save your Bitmap from data[]
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
 BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
 int quality = 100;

 String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "myImage.jpg"

 File mediaFile = new File(filePath);

 try {

      fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

      return pictureFile;
 } finally {
      if (bos != null) {
      try {
           bos.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      // ignore close error
      }
 }
```

Comment: where is picturefile variable comes from?