# Save images and Strings in exit

Tags: java, android

i want to save a List of images and list of String when i exit from my app (when i will open my app again i will can manipulate them)

i didnt find how can i implement it.

i only found that i can save my detailes with this:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
    e.putString("pathreturned", path);
    e.commit();
```

however i didnt find how can i save list (of Bitmap or String) or photo?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to save images in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830483/how-to-save-images-in-android) This discusses not to SD card and suggests that you save files to a SQLite database as BLOB's.

Alternatively, [Save image to sdcard from drawble resource on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android) highlights how to save it to the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but you have to save the image on the sd card and you can use it as below...

```
SharedPreferences mypref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=mypref.edit();
edit.putString("imagepath","/sdcard/imagename.jpeg");
edit.commit();
```