# Converting bitmap to byteArray android

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, base64

I have a bitmap that I want to send to the server by encoding it to base64 but I do not want to compress the image in either png or jpeg.

Now what I was previously doing was.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, byteArrayBitmapStream);
byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
//then simple encoding to base64 and off to server
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Now I just dont want to use any compression nor any format plain simple byte[] from bitmap that I can encode and send to the server.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use [`copyPixelsToBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) to move the pixel data to a `Buffer`, or you can use [`getPixels()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and then convert the integers to bytes with bit-shifting.

`copyPixelsToBuffer()` is probably what you'll want to use, so here is an example on how you can use it:

```
//b is the Bitmap

//calculate how many bytes our image consists of.
int bytes = b.getByteCount();
//or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
//int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

byte[] array = buffer.array(); //Get the underlying array containing the data.
```

Comment: byte[] b ;
  
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmapPicture.getByteCount()); 
  bitmapPicture.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
  b = byteBuffer.array();

???

Comment: @AsadKhan I added an example.

Comment: Thank you 
I will check it out

Comment: @AsadKhan whats the bitmapPicture in your comment. I do not find any method as getByteCount() in bitmap object.

Comment: Hey @Jave, so even if you convert bitmap to a byte array you can't necessarily tell whether mBuffer was null or not.

Comment: @ShailAdi to call getByteCount() you will nedd API level 12.

Comment: If you look at the getByteCount() impl it's simply getRowBytes() * getHeight(), do the math yourself if you're targeting < API 12.

Comment: This doesn't work, it is better to get byte array using bitmap.compress(...)

Comment: @iDemigod The OP explicitly did not want to use Bitmap.Compress().

Answer (score 9):

instead of the following line in @jave answer:

```
int bytes = b.getByteCount();
```

Use the following line and function:

```
int bytes = byteSizeOf(b);

protected int byteSizeOf(Bitmap data) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
    return data.getRowBytes() * data.getHeight();
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    return data.getByteCount();
} else {
      return data.getAllocationByteCount();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap);
```

is helpful to find the required size of the ByteBuffer