# Can not access the mBuffer

Tags: android

I use the below code:

```
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( 720, 1280, Config.ARGB_8888 );

byte []data = myBmp.mBuffer ????
```

But I find that the mBuffer of android.graphics.Bitmap can not be accessed. And there is no hint for this in Eclipse.

How to solve this？

Comment: no constant or method available in [android.graphics.Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class with the name of `mBuffer`. you can see [Converting bitmap to byteArray android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191871/converting-bitmap-to-bytearray-android) post for getting byte array from Bitmap

Comment: Hey @ρяσѕρєяK, so even if you convert bitmap to a byte array you can't necessarily tell whether mBuffer was null or not.