# Convert Bitmap to Byte array WITHOUT Bitmap.CompressFormat

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

Is there a way to convert bitmap to byte array without the Bitmap.CompressFormat class in Android? if not, how comes? if its is possible, please let me know how, thanx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
//b is the Bitmap

//calculate how many bytes our image consists of.
int bytes = b.getByteCount();
//or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
//int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

byte[] array = buffer.array(); //Get the underlying array containing the data.
```

From; https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192092/1868384

Comment: is it possible to save this array as jpg without using the Bitmap.CompressFormat? @Stephan