# Send image from android part and receive it from pc, but the image is corrupted

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to send an `jpeg` image from my android phone through socket and from the PC part, get the sent data and store it in an `jpg` file.

I'm pretty sure that I configured the socket correctly, as I can download data (binary file) from PC to android and save it correctly.

I can also read the stream which is sent from android to PC. The packet length and header information are exactly what I expect.

The problem is in reading image data. I'm getting same size for image data but when I save it to `.jpg` file, it is corrupted and I can not view it.

**Here is my Android code that tries to send image file after sending header information:**

```
try{
        //packagesize is header information which is sent in advance
        index.putInt(packagesize);

        byte c[]= {index.get(3),index.get(2),index.get(1),index.get(0)};

        InputStream jpgimage = new FileInputStream(fileimage);          

        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        int writeBytes = 0,len = 0;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

        while((len = jpgimage.read(buffer,0,buffer.length))!=-1)
        {
            writeBytes+=len;                
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,len);

        }       

        dataOutputStream.flush();
        jpgimage.close();
        dataInputStream.close();
        dataOutputStream.close();

         ...
         ...
         ...
 }
 catch statements here
```

**This is the receiving code in the PC part:**

```
    // after reading header information I try to read image data

    char *buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * jpeg_length); 

unsigned int byteCount = 0;
unsigned int byteCount = 0;
do
{
    int ret = recv(socket, buff+readBytes, jpeg_length-readBytes, 0);
    if (ret <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error receiving jpeg file.\n");
        fclose( output );
        return 106;
    }
            readBytes += ret;

    fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), readBytes, output);
}
while (readBytes < jpeg_length);

fclose( output );
```

I also have to mention that the receiving part is working fine when I send image data with PC client application which is pure `C++`.

Is there any idea about what is the problem and why I get corrupted image sending from android device?

Appreciate it.

**Edited**
I add this the to android application for testing if the sending bytes can form a good image or not? I saved the image and it was OK.

```
int writeBytes = 0,len = 0;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
// Here I save all sending bytes to an image called test.jpg
String path = "sdcard/download/images/test.jpg"; 
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path); 

        while((len = jpgimage.read(buffer,0,buffer.length))!=-1)
        {
            writeBytes+=len;
            stream.write(buffer); 
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,len);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

        }
        stream.flush();

        dataOutputStream.flush();
        jpgimage.close();
        dataInputStream.close();
        dataOutputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for that. The problem was from Android side. So I did the following changes:

I changed `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` to `BufferedOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` respectively :

```
try{
    //packagesize is header information which is sent in advance
    index.putInt(packagesize);

    byte c[]= {index.get(3),index.get(2),index.get(1),index.get(0)};

    InputStream jpgimage = new FileInputStream(fileimage);          

    dataOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    dataInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    int writeBytes = 0,len = 0;
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

    while((len = jpgimage.read(buffer,0,buffer.length))!=-1)
    {
        writeBytes+=len;                
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,len);

    }       

    dataOutputStream.flush();
    jpgimage.close();
    dataInputStream.close();
    dataOutputStream.close();

     ...
     ...
     ...
```

}
 catch statements here

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Bitmap` class to convert you image to `ByteBuffer` and then send it across and on the other end convert `ByteBuffer` to image.

**On Sender Side**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("ImageD2.jpg");
int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] array = buffer.array();
```

Now you can send `byte[]` as normal data.

**On receiving side**

receive the array normally and convert it back to `Bitmap`

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array , 0, array .length);
```

for more information you can read following questions

[Converting bitmap to byteArray android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191871/converting-bitmap-to-bytearray-android)

[How to convert byte array to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

Comment: My receiving side is not java. so how can I decode byteArray to bitmap and save it to jpeg file in c++ PC part? By the way, Would that really solve the problem. cause I can save the bytes to image properly in android part(see edited post)

Comment: @HamidBazargani try writing those bytes directly to a file.

Comment: Did not work. it goes to infinite loop while reading in receiving side.

Comment: Can you show the code where you send the file size? Have you consider the byte order? Just in case. I've made a lot of image transfer PC-Android on both sides and it Works without probelms.

Comment: @ja_mesa I send file size with 4 bytes as a part of header data before sending an image. I get it in PC correctly. Can you send me the code for PC-Android transfer please