# Byte array to bitmap converting issue

Tags: android, arrays, android-bitmap

I am trying to implement [Converting bitmap to byteArray android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191871/converting-bitmap-to-bytearray-android/10192092#10192092). I need to convert my byte[] to bitmap without compression. But everytime im getting whole black image. How to do it?

What I am doing:

```
            int bytes = bmp.getByteCount();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
            bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] resarray = buffer.array();
```

And here how I get it to bitmap:

```
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new 
            BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(barray,0, barray.length,options);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resdetayimage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);`
```

***EDIT***
Bitmap factory decode only compressed things. Thats why my code not work. So I need something like:

```
    Bitmap.Config configBmp = Bitmap.Config.valueOf(bitmap.getConfig().name());
    Bitmap bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, configBmp);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
    bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

But the code still not working. How can I implement this ? I got byte[] from intent.

Comment: I am sure but can you try creating bitmap i.e Bitmap X = Bitmap.createBitmap(resarray, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmpgetConfig());

Comment: You should do the reverse of copyPixelsToBuffer(). So is there a read pixels from buffer or something like that? DecodeByteArray expects a jpg file in that array. Not pixels. I think it returns null now. Please check. So not `a black image`.

Comment: Its not returning null already checked

Answer (score 0):

Convert bitmap to byteArray

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bStream);
byte[] mByteArray = bStream.toByteArray();
```

Convert byteArray to Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mByteArray , 0, mByteArray.length);
```

Comment: I wont compress ty

Answer (score 0):

Use `copyPixelsFromBuffer()` as it is the reverse of `copyPixelsToBuffer()`.