# Saving images in sqlite with android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

I've seen examples of showing a list in android, with images. I mean, each item of the the list has an image, that is downloaded from internet. This examples I've seen them on using cache storage(saving the image using bitmaps). Now i was wondering y it can be done by using Sqlite. I want to download images from internet and showing them in a list, saving them on sqlite.

Is this possible? any examples would be useful

Comment: Yes you can save images in sqlite as blobs.

Comment: oh i see, is that a good practice?.. I mean is that advisable?

Comment: why not? knowledge is never enough.