# java.lang.NullPointerException in Blob

Tags: android, mysql, blob

I'm using `java.sql.Blob` type for images in MySql database.
When I try insert object in database I get exception "Java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object...arg0) {

    try {
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setName("haris");

        try {
            Blob blo = null;
            blo.setBytes(1, getBytes(photo));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
        }


        if (UserService.register(user)) {
            System.out.println("Successful registrationl");
        } else {
            System.out.println("API call wasn't successful");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}

 public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
     return stream.toByteArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this piece of code to store bitmaps in blobs (converted from drawable):

```
db = this.getWDB();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

         Drawable d = model.getAppIcon();
    BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
    Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

    values.put(COLUMN_ICON_BLOB, imageInByte); 

    db.insert(TABLE_APPS, null, values);
    db.close();
```

and to retrieve it from database this method is used

```
    public static Drawable convertByteArrayToDrawable( byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap) {

    Bitmap bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);

    return new  BitmapDrawable(bitMapImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have exception because Blob is an interface and setBytes is an abstract method. Check this link [how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)