# Saving pictures in sqlite db and server

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which user has an option to attach n number of picutres till 3MB and submit it to server.  The pictures along with other information needs to be saved in android db as well as on the server db.   So Is there any restriction while inserting the picture in db & let me know in what format should it be inserted?
At one point of time the pic needs to be populated back from db and should be able to view it both on device and webapp from db in server.

Comment: You can check my answer here to get code snippet  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607032/java-lang-nullpointerexception-in-blob/14607680#14607680   in my case stored images was tiny icons and that worked pretty good. If your images are large you should consider storing only path to the file in the database

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to save images in a sqlite database. The performance will not be good. If you want do that you have to use BLOBS (Binary large objects - > http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Images are usually better off stored in the filesystem. You can insert meta data (path to image, name of pic, other information) into an sqlite Database an load the images from file system.