# Get Blob image and convert that image into Bitmap image

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, arrays, blob

I am getting image from database in blob format. i want to convert it into Bitmap image.the code i used to convert bitmap to Blob is put below.but please tell me how to reverse it.???

```
ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
btmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, boas ); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] byteArrayImage = boas .toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: edit and format your question properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will work

```
byte[] byteArray = DBcursor.getBlob(columnIndex);  

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0 ,byteArray.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple static function, It is super easy to implement and reuse :)

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0 ,bytes.length);
        }
        return null;
 }
```