# How to Save Images In Database (SQLite) and load it to View : Android

Tags: android, eclipse

How To Save Images In Database And Reload It To View In Image View?
Don't Save Directory To Show Images, Move File(Image) To Database

Android Version 2.2

Comment: instead of saving images in Database, only storing its location is encouraged.

Comment: Check this answer : [Image TO BLOB SQLITE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7331698/1654759)

Comment: @AdhikariBishwash I Need To Import And Export Images To DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for saving image :

```
private void saveDownloadedImage(Bitmap bmp, String id) {
    if (bmp != null) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,
                Base64.DEFAULT);

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put("picture", base64String);

        // save your base64String to DB
    }
}
```

and this for set image :

```
private Bitmap setImage(String base64String) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        if (base64String == null || base64String.equals("")) {


        } else {

            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: there is no need for base64 ... for saving images we can use blobs ... `initialValues.put("picture",  imgBytes);` will work, too

Comment: jay Thank You
@Selvin Can You Explain More?

Comment: with base64 image will be 1.37 times bigger ... you can learn more reading sqlite documentation or check  WhatsUp comment

Comment: @Selvin Please Explain More About initialValues.put("picture", imgBytes)
imgBytes ??