# how to insert image from sqlite android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, image-processing

i have another problem in my app...

here the scenario :
1. i have sqlite file that i put in asset folder 
it contain title : VARCHAR and image : ?? (will be my question at this time i use VARCHAR)

1. i have image that i store in res/drawable folder
2. i set the value in sqlite, so my database already contain some value (title and image)

my question is

is it possible to set an image value from my sqlite so i can get the image from res/draweable folder?

if it possible, what type of data should i use? and how to call it when load the data base

if it not possible? what the best way to use the image?

at this time here my sqlite helper

```
public ArrayList<DrawerItem> getItemMenu(){

    ArrayList<DrawerItem> listMenu = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbMenu";

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            DrawerItem setMenu = new DrawerItem(selectQuery, Integer.parseInt(selectQuery));
            setMenu.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
            setMenu.setImgResID(cursor.getInt(1));

            listMenu.add(setMenu);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return listMenu;
}
```

thx for your time guys to read my question...

Comment: Check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Comment: _"is it possible to set an image value from my sqlite so i can get the image from res/draweable folder?"_ what are you trying to say?

Comment: i mean like hard code data base... i want to make sqlite with data already inside when app launch... so i don`t need to store from app...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "blob" to store image.

ex: to store a image in to db

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

}

to retrieve a image from db

```
public Bitmap getImage(int i){

String qu = "select img  from table where feedid=" + i ;
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

if (cur.moveToFirst()){
    byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
    cur.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
}
if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
    cur.close();
}       

return null ;
}
```

Comment: thx for the reply, but how if i don`t want to store it first? i want to write it directly from my sqlite editor (mozila sqlite tool)