# Android -ArrayindexboundException in setting a byte[] of image from database to Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to insert and retrieve these from SQLite database and set to image view in a custom ListView. But running the app throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

So I tried making `j=0` outside while loop. But still causes a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` in line:

```
 Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img[j], 0, img.length);
```

What should I do? I have images in the array.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


ListView prd_list;
public static Integer clas;
byte [] imge;

int j;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prd_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    DataBaseHandler dbh = new DataBaseHandler(this);


    Bitmap[] images = { BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources
            (),R.drawable.candle1),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources   
            (),R.drawable.candl3),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.candl4),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.candl5),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.candl6),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sglc10),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.senson),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.lawn)}; 

    byte[][] img = new byte[images.length][];
    for (j=0; j<images.length; j++) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        images[j].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

        // use a 2D array for img if you want to retain the byte arrays for all the bitmaps
        img[j] = bos.toByteArray();
    }


    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
    final String[] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
    String[] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    j=0;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {

        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));

        imge=cr.getBlob(cr.getColumnIndex("pimage"));
        img[j] = imge;

        pname[i] = name;
        price[i] = prprice;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, img,pname, price);
    prd_list.setAdapter(adapter);

  } 
}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final String[] pname;
private final String[] price;
private final byte[] []img;
private Context mcontext;
int j=0;

        public ListAdapter(Context c,byte[][]img,String[] pname,String[] price){
    mcontext=c;
    this.pname=pname;
    this.price=price;
    this.img=img;
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View List;
         LayoutInflater mLayoutinflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         if(convertView==null){
         List=new View(mcontext);

         List=mLayoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
         }
         else{
         List = (View)convertView;
         }

         TextView textView1 = (TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_name);
         TextView textView2 = (TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_price);
         ImageView imageview= (ImageView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_img);
         textView1.setText(pname[position].toString());
         textView2.setText("Rs "+price[position] +" /-");
             Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img[j], 0, img[j].length);
             imageview.setImageBitmap(b1);

         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return List;

    }

}
```

**EDITED**

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
   public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "product";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "pid";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "pname";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "pspec";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET = "pprice";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY = "pfeature";
   public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "pimage";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(pimage BLOB,pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,pname TEXT,pprice NUMERIC,pspec TEXT,pfeature TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(pimage,pname,pprice,pspec) VALUES('img[0]','Candle stick 1',4000,'Solar garden / pathway light,Solar Panel:1pc crystal silicon solar cell, Battery:1pc 1.2V Ni-MH/Ni-CD AA battery 600MA ,Material:Stainless steel ,WaterProof and safe ')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(pimage,pname,pprice,pspec) VALUES('img[1]','Candle stick 3','4500','Solar garden / pathway light, Solar Panel:1pc crystal silicon solar cell, Battery:1pc 1.2V Ni-MH/Ni-CD AA battery 600MA, Material:Stainless steel, WaterProof and safe IP44 ')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(pimage,pname,pprice,pspec) VALUES('img[2]','Candle stick 5',3500,'Solar garden / pathway light, Solar Panel:1pc crystal silicon solar cell, Battery:1pc 1.2V Ni-MH/Ni-CD AA battery 600MA, Material:Stainless steel, WaterProof and safe IP44 ')");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addEntry( byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put("pimage",   image);
    db.insert( "product", null, cv );
}

public void addEntries(byte[][] img) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < img.length ; j++) 
        addEntry(img[j] );
}

}
```

Comment: where you are initializing `j` in `ListAdapter` class?

Comment: let me know what you are trying to do?

Comment: what happening when you are using `img[position]` ?

Comment: means it's working then why you are using `j` instead of  `position` ?

Comment: it's probably a different problem, but I think you want to use Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img[j], 0, img[j].length); for the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the length of the byte array you are decoding to decodeByteArray. You are using a 2D array, you need to need to specify the length of byte array containing the image, not the length of the array of byte arrays.

Change

```
Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img[j], 0, img.length);
```

to

```
Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img[j], 0, img[j].length);
```

Comment: Did you change anything else? Like to use [position] instead of [j], and setting all your images from the database instead of just index 0?

Comment: yeah.I just use j++ in while loop. I think it is not the problem.Is that the way I inserted image into database?

Comment: It looks like you are just inserting a string into the database, not an actual image.

Comment: then how to insert actual image?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Comment: I  edited my DataBaseHandler class using content value.But still not showing off my images.Is my code correct?please help.