# How to retrieve a large BLOB from database in android?

Tags: java, android

I save an image byte to database like this.

```
 byte[] imagebyte = getBytes(bitmap);
 boolean isuploaded = myDb.insertData("all_receipts",imagebyte);




 public byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);

    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

And then I have a retrieve method I created in my database helper class to retrieve all the data.

```
   public ArrayList<Model.Receipts> convertoArray(String tablename){
    ArrayList<Model.Receipts> receiptsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Model.Receipts receipt;

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM all_receipts";


    if(tablename.equalsIgnoreCase("all_receipts")){

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int indexnumber = cursor.getInt(0);
                Bitmap image = getImage(cursor.getBlob(1));
                receipt = new Model.Receipts(image,indexnumber);

                receiptsArrayList.add(receipt);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return receiptsArrayList;

}
```

This was working fine with thumbnail of the image i captured from camera. But when I use the same method for a full sized image, it does not work. I get the error

> ```
> Unable to start activity 
>
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from
> ```
>
> CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data >from it. at
>
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) at >android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) at ?>android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) at >android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)

```
From which I know that it's because that the BLOB is too big in the database.
```

So how can I call **all** the images from the database ?

Comment: The recommended way is to not store the images in the database, instead store the images as images and store the path to the image in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the path of the image into the database and the use the path to access/display the image.

---

#### An Example

The following is an example where, for convenience, the images (image001.JPG through to image010.JPG) are stored in the assets folder.

The example displays a list (ListView) of the images, along with 1 image and clicking on an item in the list changes the display to show the respective image via the stored path.

First the layout **activity_main.xml** (*note package name would have to be changed accordingly*) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.sqliteexamples.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/imagelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="myImage"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The DatabaseHelper **ImgDBHelper.java**

```
public class ImgDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "myimagestore";
    public static final String TBLNAME = "images";
    public static final String ID_COL = "_id";
    public static final String DSCR_COL = "description";
    public static final String PATH_COL = "path"; //<<<<<<<<

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    ImgDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,1);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {    
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBLNAME + "(" +
                ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                DSCR_COL + " TEXT," +
                PATH_COL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void addImageRow(String path, String description) {
        Cursor csr = db.query(TBLNAME,null,PATH_COL + "=?",new String[]{path},null,null,null);

        // DO NOT ADD DUPLICATE IMAGES (according to path)
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
            csr.close();
            return;
        }
        csr.close();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DSCR_COL,description);
        cv.put(PATH_COL,path);

        db.insert(TBLNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllImages() {
        return db.query(TBLNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public String getImagePathFromID(long id) {
        String rv = "";
        Cursor csr = db.query(TBLNAME,
                null,
                "_id=?",
                new String[]{Long.toString(id)},
                null,null,null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PATH_COL));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean areImagesLoaded() {
        Cursor csr = db.query(TBLNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        boolean rv = (csr.getCount() > 0);
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

And the Activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Drawable d;                        // drawable for the image
    String imagepath = "image001.JPG"; // initial image
    ImgDBHelper imgdbhlpr;             // DB Helper
    ListView imagelist;                // ListView
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;           // ListView's Cursor adapter
    Cursor images;                     // Cursor for the ListView
    ImageView iv;                      // The ImageView to display the image

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imagelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);

        imgdbhlpr = new ImgDBHelper(this);

        // Load the table if there are no images
        if (!imgdbhlpr.areImagesLoaded()) {
            for (int i=1;i < 11;i++) {

                String path = "image" +
                        String.format("%03d",i) +
                                ".JPG"
                        ;
                imgdbhlpr.addImageRow(path,"Image " +
                String.format("%03d",i));
            }
        }

        // get a cursor with all of the rows
        images = imgdbhlpr.getAllImages();

        // prepare the listview's adapter
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                images,
                new String[]{ImgDBHelper.DSCR_COL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );

        // set the Listview's onItemClick listener so that clicking an
        // item displays the respective image
        imagelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                iv.setImageDrawable(d = getImageFromAssets(
                        imgdbhlpr.getImagePathFromID(l)
                ));
            }
        });
        imagelist.setAdapter(sca);

        // set the initial image (image001.JPG)
        d = getImageFromAssets(imagepath);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    }


    // routine to create a drawable according to the supplied path
    private  Drawable getImageFromAssets(String imagepath) {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = am.open(imagepath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is,null);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                is = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

When initially run :-

[image]

And then after clicking on the Listview (image004) :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to store image in a database.. Instead store the URI pointing to the image.. And store the image in folder.

If you still want to store it as bytes in DB.. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630349/how-to-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-android).

But remember there is a limit of 1MB on the cursor size.