# Problems saving and retrieving images

Tags: android, arrays, database, image, android-sqlite

Ok i'm completely editing this post... I have made it so that I can save the file path to my data base.  this works and is saved as /storage/emulated/0/1508blah blah.jpg .  Now i cannot get my code to read this item back into a picture.

```
    imagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_image);
    Toast.makeText(this, recipe.image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(recipe.image));
            imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

am I missing something here? cause the Toast Is reading the recipe.image just fine and is displaying the path.  why Is the rest not displaying the image?

Storage Code

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    String picturePath = destination.toString();
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textImagePath.setText(picturePath.toString());
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.addphotoview);
    img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: Using BLOBs is an **anti-pattern**. Do yourself (and your users) a favour: save the file paths or URLs only.

Comment: What do you mean , can you provide an example or direct me to a link with an example of this.  cause Ive done really good with this app thus far, but these images seem to be kicking my butt.

Comment: Paths and URLS are strings. Plain strings. There's not a lot to discuss about.

Comment: I am aware they are strings, I'm not sure how i would go about saving and retrieving the image file this way.

Comment: everything i have done on this app so far has been self contained or user input

Comment: @Koumintang, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518604/how-to-retrieve-a-large-blob-from-database-in-android/46519680#46519680)

Comment: @MikeT  Thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Koumintang to save as BLOB use something along the lines of `values.put(Recipe.KEY_IMAGE, recipe.image)` where recipe.image is a `byte[]` and retrieve using `getBlob()`. Note I beleive there's a 2Mb limit for a cursor.

Comment: If you store a path, then you reload the image from the file system. What's difficult in this?

Comment: ok So i found out it isnt writing the whole file path for some reason... it stops at the /storage/emulated/0/(filename) when the file is actually saving to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/(different file name).   if my code is telling it where to store why would it store it elsewhere and with a different file name? I have even tried overriding the save location by typing my own in there but no change to where it saves.

Comment: I believe i found the culprit as to why it wont create the file/directory... I've got a warning on the destination.createNewFile.  saying it s being ignored... I've not found a sure fire way to fix this... and Ideas would be great... I have no idea what would even  cause it to be ignored.... I have the permissions done in the manifest.

Comment: even if i try to do a mkdir call, those get ignored as well... i'm confused would it be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in the files paths seem to be the best solution to the problem i am having so that you @ModularSynth for your help with this.  Always making sure all the info is your code to make the file paths work helps.