# How do apps like Google Keep and Evernote save images?

Tags: android, database, image

I am interested in how the mechanics of several note taking apps work. Many of them allow the user to add images and similar to notes. I know that it's possible to save the note's text etc. into a database, but how and where are the images being stored?

What is the most convenient way to achieve this? My guess was that a thumbnail or a compressed file gets created and saved in a certain directory, then the file's path will be stored to the database.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/master/src/com/android/camera   re: imageManager , imageLoader, bitmapManager   may provide some background on <img />

Comment: They just save the image on a file and keep the ref to it.

Answer (score 2):

these apps may use external directories, but there is also a way to store data (as bytes, column type named `BLOB`) directly in database. [check out this question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it) for more info

note that storing large size files in database isn't most efficient way.

if you want to know how these apps are storing images root your device and use [SQLite debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin&hl=pl) (or other way) to look into other apps databases (then you may find above mentioned `BLOB` columns). or check your device storage (internal and external) for folders with these image files (oftenly apps are creating folders with `.` in theirs filename, which in `Unix` based systems mean that folder is hidden)