# Image Upload In SQLite Database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-gallery

I have google about how to insert. But cant get any proper answer.
I have to insert image from gallery to sqlite database. i have tried .but cant perform image insertion.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
protected static ImageView imPhoto;
DatabaseHelperAdapter databaseHelperAdapter;

Button btnSubmit;

private String selectedImagePath;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Register");

    databaseHelperAdapter = new DatabaseHelperAdapter(this);



    imPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imPhoto);


    imPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            imPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}






//Insert into database
public void addUser(View view) throws IOException {



    byte[] byteImage1;
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
    BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream);
    byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()];
    bif.read(byteImage1);





    byte[] image = byteImage1;

    long id = databaseHelperAdapter.insertData(fname, lname, password, email, birthday, gender, image);

    if (id < 0) {

        Message.message(this, "Record not inserted");
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Message.message(this, "Record Inserted Successfully");
    }
}


}
```

2]Database File

```
import java.sql.Blob;

public class DatabaseHelperAdapter {

    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    DatabaseHelper helper;

    public DatabaseHelperAdapter(Context context) {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertData(String fname, String lname, String password, String email, String birthday, String gender, byte[] image) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.LNAME, lname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.BIRTHDAY, birthday);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.GENDER, gender);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE, String.valueOf(image));

        long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return id;
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.EMAIL + " =?", new String[]{email}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }

    public DatabaseHelperAdapter open() {

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LoginForm";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "LoginTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        private static final String UID = "_id";
        private static final String FNAME = "FName";
        private static final String LNAME = "LName";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";
        private static final String EMAIL = "Email";
        private static final String BIRTHDAY = "Birthday";
        private static final String GENDER = "Gender";
        private static final String IMAGE = "Image";


        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
                + FNAME + " VARCHAR(255) , "
                + LNAME + " VARCHAR(255) ,"
                + PASSWORD + " text ,"
                + EMAIL + " VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE ,"
                + BIRTHDAY + " VARCHAR(255) ,"
                + GENDER + " VARCHAR(255)"
                + IMAGE +" BLOB );";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        private Context context;


        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "Constructor is called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {

                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                Message.message(context, "onCreate is called");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            try {
                Message.message(context, "onUpdates is called");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

3]error log:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
            at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
            at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at com.example.zeronesnatik.loginform11.MainActivity.addUser(MainActivity.java:170)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
09-18 13:01:42.903    2178-2532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.zeronesnatik.loginform11/.MainActivity
09-18 13:01:42.962    2178-7631/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-18 13:01:42.973    2178-7631/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-18 13:01:42.973    2178-7631/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9deff340, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-18 13:01:43.420    2178-2199/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{3e0c9d7b u0 com.example.zeronesnatik.loginform11/.MainActivity t43 f}
09-18 13:01:44.059    2178-2334/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

Comment: Avoid storing images in sqlite, it will make your database heavy and increase response time. try to copy image to your app's folder in SD card and save image path in your database

Comment: Agree with JaiSoni .. You just have to store image path in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier solution would be to save on Database only the path of your Image as given by `SELECT_PICTURE` Intent. Anyway, if you're forced to save the image contents, I believe the problem to be in line:

```
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE, String.valueOf(image));
```

Because you're passing to a byte column (BLOB) a simple String. BLOBs are somehow tricky, you can't handle them as if they were simple strings. Try to do the insert like this, with bind statement:

```
SQLiteStatement insertStmt      =   db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO ....");
insertStmt.clearBindings();
insertStmt.bindBlob(3, (byte[])yourImageData);
insertStmt.executeInsert();
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it) to see other blob handling techniques such as `Bitmap.CompressFormat` and base64 encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save image or heavy data in sqlite, as it reduce the performance. You can save image file path in database, and you want to do any operation on image, you can get the image using -`File file = new File(SAVED_IMAGE_FILE_PATH);`