# How to view image inserted in real device?

Tags: android, image, apk

Is it possible to view inserted image in android? Which app should I use? I using [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin&hl=en) to access database contents and seeing a `<BLOB>` in the image column. Does it has a way to see the image inserted in `SQLite Debugger`?

Comment: See Answer for Similar Question here :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

Comment: @VishalBhadani If I just want to view inserted image in real device, what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Query Table**

```
Cursor cur=your query;
while(cur.moveToNext())
{
     byte[] photoblob=cur.getBlob(index of blob column);
}
```

**Now Convert byte[] photo to image:**

```
ByteArrayInputStream imagestrm = new ByteArrayInputStream(photoblob);
Bitmap img= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestrm);
```

Now you can set Bitmap to Imageview.

I hope you will get my point.