# Save image- how should i call my method

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

Ive been trying to save my image into the SQLite database. But I can't solve it by my own. I've already tried in my opinion everything, but it does not work. So my question is if ive got **this method:**

```
    private byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Middle value is quality, but PNG is lossless, so it's ignored.
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

and i've got this to take a photo and pick image from gallery.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView_Fotak.setImageBitmap(photo);


    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri_vybrana = data.getData();
        imageView_VyberFotku.setImageURI(imageUri_vybrana);
        imageView_VyberFotku = getBitmapAsByteArray();
```

How should I do it to convert my image for example from gallery to a BLOB? What method i should call?
I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: You can try saving your image in another way. 
Save the image on the internal storage, and get its path and save that path in your SQLite database. Next time you want that image, you can just get the path from the database and fetch that image from that path.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need to save it in the form of BLOB. And my problem is i don't know how to convert my image even if i have method that should do it. I mean how should i call something like image.getsBitmapAsByteArray() ....

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Comment: Yes, I've already checked this and hundred more articles, but still don't know.

Comment: Is there any error you are seeing or anything null ?
What is happening actually with your current code ?

Comment: Actually i cant even run it... I don't know how to convert my specific image , how should i use the convert method

Comment: Are you event getting the image or bitmap  ? Are you able to set the picked image to UIImageView ?
First do that.

Comment: I can show my code. That would be very helpfull and i would be very gratefull. I think is something stupid but I'm starting to be desperate.

Comment: Yes, you need to show the code

Comment: I've already asked question here, but it's been for some reason blocked as duplicated. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140486/android-save-image-from-camera-and-gallery-into-sqlite-database-in-form-of-bl)

Comment: In that code, you haven't put the image in your method named
 "dbOperace.pridejInformace(db, Sirka_0m);"

Where is the byte array here in the method ?

To convert image to byte array , the below lines would do the work, which you have already written. The only missing thing is BITMAP.

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Comment: Excuse me, i know i looked like complete idiot but i'm not sure that i understand what you mean

Comment: Still cant figured it out. Could you please write the code you mean. That would be really awesome! And very helpfull

Comment: I've done this but it's show me an error `byte[] ObrazekGalerie = params[2];
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbOperace.getWritableDatabase();
            dbOperace.pridejInformace(db, Sirka_0m, ObrazekGalerie);`

Comment: If you could send me your code , I can check it and fix it.

Comment: By code I mean the project zip.

Comment: That would be awesome man! You are really great and kind!! here is the project [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B19AM1KNZyS7LWF2RjR5cmdaaDA)

Comment: Okay, I will check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to your updated project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsv947j7susfcer/Formular1.00.zip?dl=0

It works for the image from gallery, same way you can make it work for camera image also.

Check the image, you can see blob saved.

[image: See the image]

Comment: Yes. You need a bitmap either from camera picture or from gallary image