# Unable to convert BLOB to string "Only SQL select statements"

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I have a working application with a sql lite database just short of 170 records. I only have select statements no CRUD just the select statements. When i select from my list view and the record number is greater than 125 "Selection >= Record 125" it crashes with the ***Unable to convert BLOB to string*** however for the first 124 records all of them work perfectly here is my code snippet below any assistance would be appreciated. I have consulted all the other questions however all of them relate to inserts and updates as where my app works up until a certain record Number in my database

**My code,**

```
    String[] details = new String[9];
    Human hmn = null;
    List<Human> humanList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Human WHERE Human.IdentNr = " + Number,null);
    if (cursor != null ) {
        if  (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               details[0] = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Nr")));
               details[1] = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("IdentNr")));
               details[2] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));
               details[3] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Type"));
               details[4]= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WalkDist"));
               details[5] =String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Food")));
               details[6] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Relationship"));
               details[7] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Status"));
               details[8] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ImageName"));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    closeDatabase();
```

The above snippet is from a method that accepts Number as a int and returns details array

Comment: try this one "cursor.getBlob()"

Comment: The array is string so I convert it to type blob? @RaseemAyatt

Comment: yes convert it to blob

Comment: Apparently, the 125th record contains a blob. Would this be valid?

Comment: i duplicted record 1 in place of 125 and still no luck please provide a snippet with how blob can convert to this array.... @RaseemAyatt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it  please check this link

Comment: I seem to have fixed it my database ad 1 row that the pk was duplicated for some reason its set to auto increment so dont understand how it can just have two of the same but record 140 had the same pk duplicated i deleted that record and its working again

Comment: Thanks for your assistance