# how to save bytes data in a csv file and insert it in android sqlite blob field

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I have an image save as blob in SQLite database,Now i want that image blob data to be saved on a file and i also need to insert the blob data from the file back into the database.I actually want this to be done pragmatically done using android.Any ideas how to do it?Don't tell me to show some research i have done.I'm new to android programming and trying to learn.So please help me.

Omg its not a duplicate question.The question is how to fetch blob data from a database and save it in a seperate file(May b csv file) and insert bytes data from file into sqlite db.

```
try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_USER_PROFILE, null);
        int rowcount = 0;
        int colcount = 0;
        File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String filename = "userProfile.csv";

        // the name of the file to export with
        File saveFile = new File(sdCardDir, filename);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFile);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        rowcount = c.getCount();
        colcount = c.getColumnCount();
        if (rowcount > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < colcount; i++) {
                if (i != colcount - 1) {

                    bw.write(c.getColumnName(i) + ",");

                } else {

                    bw.write(c.getColumnName(i));

                }
            }
            bw.newLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
                c.moveToPosition(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
                    if (j != 7) {
                        if (j != colcount - 1)
                            bw.write(c.getString(j) + ",");
                        else
                            bw.write(c.getString(j));
                    } else
                        bw.write((c.getBlob(7)) + ",");
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.flush();
            Log.e("tag", "Exported Successfully.");
            Log.e("tag", "Exported Successfully to" + sdCardDir);
        }
        c.close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("catch", ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

Comment: Start from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Comment: no no,,,i know how to insert and retrive blob from sqlite.Now i need to know how to fetch blobl data from sqlite and save it in a seperate file and is it possible to insert the blob data from the seperate file into the database..Am I clear? @M.WaqasPervez

Comment: yes it is possilbe. You just have to write a normal file with blob data. For reading and writing of files : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android

Comment: Ya,i tried it in csv file.but for some strange reason I couldn't convert it back to an image

Comment: please show what have you done. a sample of code you tried. and i think `txt` file would have been more easy.

Comment: can you please check my updated Question @M.WaqasPervez

Comment: What exception are you getting. did u check the logs ?

Comment: no exception or problem...i tried to insert the data back into db and when retrieved it viewed in a imageview..i was not able to see any image