# How store and read a BLOB in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I'm using ContentValues to put data on SQLite, but I don't know to put the image on database. I know that I need convert to byte[], but how? The image is .JPG.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Product.ID,product.getId());
```

I receive the follow content of web:

```
Key: image_small -- Value: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
               HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
               MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCABAAEADASIA
               AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
               AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
               ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
               p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
               AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
               BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
               U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
               uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3+iii
               gAorD/tvz7i7sLMRS6rAzf6NMzxLjPyksFbCkc5APPFRyXviiME/2Hpz4HSLVWJP/fUApgdBRWBp
               nivT76Y2srSWt6nE1rcqUeFvRj90g9iCQ3UE1Uv7nXW1eZ4ILp9OjZRH5AQb8BSx5OTzkfSiwHVU
               ViaJfzXU80cyX6AKCourUx4PfDYwe3FbdIAooooA4Lw/rl9farfTwwNOrsWK+eEVewAz1wOM+tbl
               7rF/DEjfYXhfeMeZNCVfg5H3wenP4Vh+GAItcv41UKqtIAoGAAHPSusaR1K7FDZPOWx/+utJLUkz
               W1a4keCQadPLEVw7fZw+DnqpUnPepY9dCTyJPbXEUIOUka2lXI44xt+tU7iU2zmOXxBJC4+YiWCE
               4B9wgFT2t1KSIE1q1nnwflaABjznOFcdBnp9akZbHiLTOhvIkP8AtuV/9CArRtLqK8txNC6PGSQG
               RgwODjqKqecx6M+M9yauWvNsh+v86GgRNRRRUjOC0M7PE+pL/wBNJR/5ENdJPEk4ActxnpXLaXNH
               F4t1TewX99N1/wB81meJPF3i3T9euLXRvDqX1gioY5/s0rliUBblWA4JI6dq6Iwc3ZGU5qCuztft
               LW0gXzJ1T/aU/wAsVGjQu5wXLAnkIw61yq6/rUse6TyY328r/Yd9wfTIalXX9YVNy/ZyQgIB0a/5
               OOnfvxml7N/1cPaL+rHaA7RjJPuTWnaf8esf0rz/AMP+JNXv9ZuLTVNKS2tUt/MS8WCeJXfco2Yl
               A7En8K7+yIayhYHIKgg1FSLjoyoS5tR7TBf4JD9FzVaTVLeH/WCVfrGau0VGhZ41N4ksdH8S6h9v
               uWtkaeUo8isFcFiVIPQ8Gnp8SNOIazfULY2qzGVJlkYsQf4cfia9iopuVxWPGD8RIriwjja6jWe2
               jCRNGJG8wgg5bC8dP1q8PH1pdu9xcfaFlkOSkNrM6rxgc7favWaKVwseUr4ys2PyQaq/+5p85/8A
               Za9I0cudItTLHJG5jDMkgwy55wR2NXqKG7jP/9k=
```

Comment: Maybe [storing it as a BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it) would work?

Comment: You might also consider storing it as a file and just storing the path in the database.

Comment: Right. However, how I create a image by the crazy data that I received?