# Android SQLite database: "Column does not exist" when it does

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The database is created using a SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String SQL_CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + InventoryEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_IMAGE + " BLOB, "
            + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE + " REAL NOT NULL, "
            + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " INTEGER, "
            + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE);
}
```

All the constants are defined in a contract, this is the `COLUMN_PRODUCT_IMAGE` one:

```
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_IMAGE = "image";
```

In a CursorAdapter, I try to access the `image` column from the `bindView` method, after adding some random data to the database:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
    byte [] bytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_IMAGE));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmap(bytes);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

This produces an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'image' does not exist`

I double checked the database using windows cmd, here's how it looks:

```
sqlite> select * from inventory;
_id         image       name        price       quantity    description
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
1                       ff          5.0         5           fds
```

Column 'image' exists, so why the error?

Comment: Are you adding the column to the selection when you create the cursor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

Comment: the `projection` used to obtain the `cursor` might lack column `image`.

Comment: As you said, I forgot to add it to the projection when querying the database, I fixed it now and all works fine. Thank you sirs!