# BitmapFactory.decodeFile does not work for me

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, bitmap

```
// Convert image to bitmap
Bitmap src1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.fried_chicken);

// Convert bitmap to byte
ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
src1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos1);
byte[] byte1 = baos1.toByteArray();

// Convert byte to blob
Blob blob1 = new SerialBlob(byte1);
```

When I do this, theres a red line for `R.drawable.fired_chicken`. Aren't I supposed to put the path file? Am I missing something? `SerialBlob` is also underlined, is this because of the previous error?

FYI: I am decoding an image into bitmap then to blob because I want to save it into a sqlite database.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgX3F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red line is because you are trying to decode a drawable (by its id) instead of a File (by a String) to decode the drawable change the line to

```
Bitmap src1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.fried_chicken);
```

For the SerialBlob error as far as I know there's no SerialBlob in Android Studio
Try checking this
[how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

Comment: thanks. do you have an idea on how to fix the `SerialBlob`?

Comment: @Micro0 sorry but just wanna make sure. To store an image into a database, it needs to be a blob right? Im new to this.
And in the link you sent me, it shows `Connection`. What am I suppose to connect to? If it is a database, i tried checking my file explore (data/data/package name) and theres no database folder even though I ran `db = new Handler(this);`

Comment: The code that you need is the insertUser method

Comment: Thanks. After some looking, I've figured out how to insert my data into the database. Thank you, you helped a lot :))))